# Image not found with Laravel's blade

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.1 andthe logic is: a user uploads an image. It goes not in the public directory but in the storage one (because I read that the storage directory is private). And I want to put the path to the image in the src=" " attribute but no image is found. I've tried:

```
<img class="getImage" src="http://localhost/bluedrive/drive/storage/uploads/1/DSC_8816.jpg">
<img class="getImage" src="C:\xampp\htdocs\bluedrive\drive\storage\uploads\1\DSC_8816.jpg">
```

But with no success...Why the pic is not found?

Answer (score 1):

The storage directory is **private**. That means it's not accessible via the browser. If you want to display the image, you'll need it somewhere in `public` or you'll need to make a Laravel route that [proxies the private images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562908/how-to-deal-with-private-images-in-laravel-5) (potentially after first checking the user's permissions to see them).

<sup>Side note: `C:\...` syntax will never work for a website, and you should avoid explicitly writing out `http://localhost/` sort of URLs. Use Laravel's `url` and `asset` helpers for this.</sup>

Comment: Well...I've also put the same image in the public directory and wrote: src="http://localhost/bluedrive/drive/public/uploads/1/DSC_8816.jpg"> But again it's not visible

Comment: remove `/public` and try like, `localhost/bluedrive/drive/uploads/1/…`, this may helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214499/laravel-5-not-finding-css-files/28214659#28214659

Comment: @Alex It should be `http://localhost/bluedrive...` rather than `localhost/bluedrive...`

Comment: @ThomasKim It is with the http:// but for the example I removed it, don't know why. Anyway - http://localhost/bluedrive/drive/public/uploads/1/DSC_8816.jpg  It is still not found

Comment: @Alex StackOverflow removes the `http://` for cleaner comments. You'll likely want to use `<img src="{{ url('uploads/1/DSC_8816.jpg') }}">`. `bluedrive/drive/public` shouldn't be part of your site's URLs - those directories aren't publicly accessible in a good setup.

Comment: @ceejayoz Already tried with url() but the picture is still no found. It's like it's not in the directory

Comment: Check your server config and permissions on the file, then.

Comment: @ceejayoz You mean the php.ini?

Comment: @Alex No, the webserver (Apache/nginx) config and whether the server's user has read access to that folder.