# Getting private images from the server with Lumen/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have to obtain, from my Front-end in Angular, private images that are stored in the server, but I don't know how to get these images without saving it in the `/public` folder that Laravel/Lumen contains.

The idea is to a GET HTTP Request with the user information and this route should return the image. Is there any way to do it, any other possibility?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how to you add the image? do you use Storage?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a "write a code that does so and so for me" service, please edit the question and add the code you have tried so far, why it didn't work, the error message if any, what you're expecting and what you're currently getting

Answer (score 1):

```php
// Storing the incoming file on the local storage driver (not public)
$filePath = request()->file_name->store('some_folder_name');

// Returning the image
return response()->file(Storage::path($filePath));
```

```html
<!-- displaying the image -->
<img src="{{ route('some_route_to_return_the_file_repsonse') }}" />
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: I just found a more extensive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562908/how-to-deal-with-private-images-in-laravel-5#answer-53310884)

Comment: If I tried doing this: `<img src="{{ route('some_route_to_return_the_file_repsonse') }}" />` Angular puts `http://localhost:4200` at the beginning and it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I hope my answer will help you.
In Laravel, there is the public disk. The public disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly accessible.
To make the connection from `/public` to `storage/app/public` you have to run:

`php artisan storage:link`

When you save a image to the public disk you will have something like:

`Storage::disk('public')->put('file.txt', 'Contents');`

To get the public image from the public disk

`Storage::disk('public')->get('file.txt');`

you can also build you own path so on put/get you can have `'custom_path/file.text'`and so on.

The complete information you can get from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem). I hope this will solve you issue.