# How can I limit/restrict users who can access files in my storage's folder? (laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-filesystem, laravel-storage

I already created a symbolic link to access the public folder from storage `storage/app/public`

```
php artisan storage:link
```

This time I'm having questions on my mind on how to filter users who can view the image? Like, How can I implement **Only Me**, **My Friends Only**?

Any ideas Sirs?

Comment: how about creating route, accessing all images there, then applying authentications and policies to set who can view images?

Comment: @Fayakon thinking bout that also, but my problem here is if I put the file in the **public** folder anyone can access it without using a route.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28562981/10697521

Answer (score 1):

> NOTE: There is a little performance issue with this solution. This is just to answer the question, scroll down more to see other approach from other.

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```

---

I personally **save** the files inside `/storage/app/files` not inside the `/public` folder (As it tells **public** for everyone).

```
request()->file->storeAs('files', 'filename.ext');
```

---

To **view & add restrictions**: create a route responsible for viewing:

```
Route::get('files/{$filename}', 'FileController@show')->name('files.show);
```

Controller:

```
public function show($filename)
{
    $path = storage_path('app/files/'.$filename);

    //do some If-Else or Filters here, for user who can access the file

    return response()->download($path, null, [], null);
}
```

---

To **delete** the file:

```
File::delete('app/files/'.$filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should set a field 'image_option' in your table 'storage_file'.

```
image_option: string,
image_option = {privacy_level:[1, 2, 3]}
privacy_level = 1 // public
privacy_level = 2 // only me
privacy_level = 3 // only friend only
```

Comment: already have a field for privacy, my problem is how to limit *restricted users* on viewing files from public folder.